# return to new post page with post content ?

Tags: php, post

Hello i am working about a articles script

i have a small problem in new post page ( new_post.php )

my form page

```
<form>
input name = "post_title"
textarea = "post_content"
</form>
```

in my proccess page i have ( php if statment )

example

```
if(empty($_POST['post_title]){
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Title field is empty !';
header("location: newpost.php");
}
```

it's working fine

but the problem is

i lost the post data if the system redirected me !

sorry for my language but i mean

the data i have writed in the text area of the post content is lost if the system redirected me to the new post page !

so , how i can keep this data without lost after redirecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the post data to a $_SESSION variable (or array) before redirecting.  That way, you can recall it later.

Comment: Thank you swayne i was thinking about that , this is the good idea , but what if the post is too big ? is the session have a max six ?

Comment: $_SESSION vars are stored in a file on the server, so the only limit I can think of is the max file size (which I think is 128mb by default).  If you don't want to store the entire $_POST, you can just store the parts you may want to recall (such as in pre-populating a form that is returned to the user).

Comment: Fantastic idea , and i think 128Mb enough milion post ! thank you very much swayne

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid redirecting by using a php function to display your form. That way you could simply pass the values as arguments to the function.

`function showForm($title="", $content=""){

{display form using the arguments as values for each form field}

}`